# Яндекс карты. Как оптимальней открывать локации по ссылке?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, yandex-maps-api

Задача открыть карту в нескольких, определенных переменными, локациях.

Не очень сложная для меня, но у меня локаций этих много - 599. Как бы оптимальней это сделать? Есть массив координат `(х, у)`, названий мест и категория места (киоск, супермаркет, фитнес и т.д.).

Нужно собрать таблицу, с вкладками категорий мест, внутри которых будут эти самые места в виде ссылки (их названия). При клике на них открывается карта по описанным внутри ссылки координатам.
Буду очень признателен за примеры.

Добавил:
А вообще, интересно и как [такое](http://www.ozon.ru/context/map/?areaId=2) устроенно. Уж очень удобно.

Comment: это называется кластеризация, в справке api полно документации.

Comment: @Jean-Claude, что именно? Вы про пример из добавленного?

Comment: да, именно так.

Comment: @Jean-Claude, спасибо, уже сделал. Проблема в названии была, т.е. я и не знал что это называется так. Как стоит поступать в похожих ситуациях?

Comment: Можно попробовать почитать по диагонали руководство разработчика https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/dg/concepts/index-docpage/ или прокликать примеры https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/. Там есть и описания, и ссылки на документацию

Answer (score -1):

В документации есть пример про вывод списка объектов, добавленных на карту https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/object_list